# offline / batch processing?

Tags: ros, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to run ROS in an offline mode in order to process every msg? For example, I just converted a .bag file with /camera/rgb/points to a sequence of .pcd files, but I had to run "rosbag play --pause " and then step through each frame by pressing 's' in order to catch every message, and get all 238 frames, instead of the ~20 frames it could do in realtime. So is there a general purpose offline processing mode that could do this automatically?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11303/offline-/-batch-processing?/) by [davidstolarsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1116/davidstolarsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-09-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [rosbag API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API) to get messages one at a time; if your code only grabs a new message every time it finishes with the previous one, you can't miss a frame.

A quicker, dirtier solution is to use the `-r` flag to `rosbag` to slow down the playback rate to something your code can handle.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davidstolarsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1116/davidstolarsky/) on 2011-09-25**:
The frame saver here is pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd; not sure if I can plug that in with your rosbag API suggestion. -r should do for now. offline_ros would be cool; step bag input frames and wait for everything to drain. I don't know how compatible this is with the ROS API.